# Documents in array matching a sequence

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider following 3 documents (simplified):

```
{
    "name" : "Alex Ham",
    "opponents" : [ 
        {
            "location" : "west",
            "position" : 5
        },
        {
            "location" : "north",
            "position" : 7
        },
        {
            "location" : "east",
            "position" : 2
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "John Flex",
    "opponents" : [ 
        {
            "location" : "north",
            "position" : 9
        },
        {
            "location" : "north",
            "position" : 4
        },
        {
            "location" : "south",
            "position" : 2
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "Adam Will",
    "opponents" : [ 
        {
            "location" : "east",
            "position" : 6
        },
        {
            "location" : "south",
            "position" : 8
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to match documents by item sequence in array `opponents`. I'll have integers such as 572, 942, 68, etc. Each digit of the integer represents `position` in `opponents` array.

For example, for 572, I need to match first document (Alex Ham), because if you look at the `opponents` array, the sequence of items and their `position` fields are 5, 7, and 2 respectively.

For 942, I've to match the second document (John Flex), and for 68, I've to match the third document (Adam Will), and so on.

Considering to have huge data (a few million documents), and taking performance into consideration, how can I build an aggregation pipeline to match document for above case.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the pipeline below which solves the problem. The basic logic is to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) while preserving index, and using index to compute the place value of the integer using the formula `position * (pow(10, size - index - 1))`

```
[
{$project: {name: 1, opponents: 1, sz: {$size: '$opponents'}}},
{$unwind: {path: '$opponents', includeArrayIndex: 'i'}},
{$project: {name: 1, opponents: 1, 
    num: {$multiply: [{$pow: [10, {$subtract: [{$subtract: ['$sz', 1]}, '$i']}]}, '$opponents.position']}
    }},
{$group: {
    _id: '$_id', 
    num: {$sum: '$num'}, 
    name: {$first: '$name'}, 
    opponents: {$push: '$opponents'}
}},
{$match: {num: 572}},
]
```

Comment: wow that seems cool can you please explain in detail of what you did in $project stage

Comment: But i think this all calculation will make your query slow,cant there be any simple way

Comment: No, these are all basic mathematical operation, which run extremely fast, since they are running in mongo internal C++ implementation.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this using $concat (aggregation) ?

Comment: and btw, the above aggregation didn't work. considering an example where there are 2 items in `opponents`, and `position` is 5 and 3 respectively, after the second `$project` (where math is located), the `num` field is 50 for the first document, and 3 for the second document. and this doesn't match anything in the next aggregation step where `{"$match" : {"num" : 53}}`

Comment: @Alex ahh. check again. I had made a silly edit without actually verifying

Comment: the `group` seems like such a heavy operation so in this case, it throw me exception saying `"errmsg" : "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in."`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to use aggregation in this case. To achieve this task with aggregation you would need to go through the whole collection and project all documents to a new form containing a value which can be matched against your input. Although aggregation is fast, that is still not good enough.

Instead I suggest formating your input to a form that can be match against the documents:

```js
const val = 572;

const arr = val.toString().split('');
const size = arr.length;

const selector = arr.map((v, i) => {
  return {
    [`opponents.${i}.position`]: parseInt(v, 10),
  };
}).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return Object.assign(acc, cur);
}, {});

selector.opponents = {
  $size: size,
};
console.log(selector);
```

Now using this new selector, you can use the normal `.find` operation to get the documents:

```
collection.find(arr);
```

Comment: What makes you think that aggregation is not fast enough, and this approach is?

Comment: Let say you have 1 million documents, then you use aggregation to project all those documents to a form that can be match against the input, and I am sure that the aggregation will be quite complicated, requires many stages. So even we know that aggregation is fast, but in this case it will still take a lot of CPU power and time.

Comment: The aggregation pipeline here will mostly be processed in the form of a stream. So, the above is true in the worst case only. Moreover, the above code relies of external application logic. Another missing part is that you dont check the size of the array. So you would end up matching 5723 along with 572.

Comment: Oh you are right about the possible wrong matching I will fix that. Could you tell me more about "the worst case"? what does it mean? because in this case, we can only use `$match` after transform stages, e.g. at the last stage or almost last, so we still need to go through all documents, right?

Comment: this looks a working solution. this is one of my options, and I am still looking to other solutions. and btw, I've 18 million documents in the collection. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Alex wow that is huge. I am very curious about the performance of my answer and the other solution answered earlier. So if you have time, could you do a performance test  of the two solutions? that would be extremely helpful :)

Comment: other answer is already failing at `group` stage due to performance problem I guess, and your answer has returned 45 matches/documents in ~13 seconds when I run it against that 18 million docs.

Comment: 13 seconds!! that sounds too long for me. Let try this: combine my answer with aggregation, wrap the `selector` value obtained by my code above inside a `$match` stage of aggregation. Like this: `collection.aggregate([{$match: selector}])`, try this and let me know the result, I will update my answer if it is better